How to determine if an obfuscated element of the sample is still in the same population (defined by the sample and sample used for value calculation)?
I want to determine the probability that a new value $X$ is part of my population. The problem is that I use my sample, not only to define my population, but also my values are created utilizing my sample.
More specifically: I have a sample consisting of about 400 similar programs. I would like to define my population as all programs doing similar things as these 400 programs.
I can calculate a similarity score between two programs through a metric. So for any program $p_i$ in my sample (of size $N$) I can calculate $N-1$ scores and then further calculate $N-1$ times the means $m_i$ of these scores.
Now I want to find out if a given program (which is actually derived from one of the programs in the sample) is a part of my population (if it is still close to the other programs). So I think I would need a hypothesis test for being part of it.
Alternatively I am also open to the idea of just having a measure of how different certain programs are from my population/sample.
Now my idea was to calculate all $N$ means ($m_i$´s) and see them as random variables of a distribution. (I am not sure if they are normally distributed, but somehow I think I could say they are, due to the magic of the central limit theorem and my sample size being bigger thirty. 1. Is this true?)
Then I could calculate $N$ (2. not $N-1$, will that be a problem?) scores between the new obfuscated program and all the other programs in the sample.
I think I could now calculate the z-score as a measure of how far the input program is apart from my distribution (how likely it is that it is still the same distribution), but the program is not a part of my sample so I don´t know if that is going to be valid.
So 3. is this approach valid? and 4. Is there a better/valid approach?.
Also, only if possible, I need to argue that my approach is valid, so you would render me a great service if you could provide any sources for your answers.
Note: this is not the first thing I tried, I consulted various literature and ChatGPT. I read about Studentization, confidence intervals, finite populations and Bootstrap sampling. However, I am very uncertain if any of these approaches are applicable since my problem unfortunately apparently is not at all "textbook".

Your first Q: Answer is NO
